# To prove the following inequalities of positive rational numbers

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

I have to prove the following inequalities:

$$ a^ab^bc^c \ge \ (\frac{a+b}{2})^{\frac{a+b}{2}} (\frac{c+b}{2})^{\frac{c+b}{2}} (\frac{a+c}{2})^{\frac{a+c}{2}} $$

$$(a+b)^{c}(c+b)^{a}(a+c)^{b} < \left(\frac{2(a+b+c)}{3}\right)^{a+b+c} ,a\ne b\ne c. $$

For the second I tried using weighted $AM > GM$ method on $a+b, b+c, c+a$ with weights $ c, a, b$.

But I am not getting the desired answer.

Comment: There is something wrong with the first inequality. set $a=b=c=1$, then LHS is $1$ and RHS is $8$.

Comment: Fixed it. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I guess $a,b,c$ are positive. When $a= -3, \, b=1, \, c=1 $, LHS is $-1/27$ and RHS is $1$

Comment: Yes they are. I mentioned it in the title of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to prove the first inequality by using weighted $AM \ge\ GM$ on $ \frac{a+b}{a}, \frac{a+b}{b}, \frac{b+c}{b}, \frac{b+c}{c}, \frac{c+a}{c}, \frac{a+c}{a} $ with weights $ \frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{2}, \frac{b}{2}, \frac{c}{2}, \frac{c}{2}, \frac{a}{2}$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach for the first question**

$f(x)=x\ln x$ is convex for all positive $x$.

Note that taking $a\ge b\ge c\,$ (WLOG) gives us $\frac{a+b}{2}\ge \frac{a+c}{2} \ge \frac{b+c}{2}$ and

\begin{align}
a+b+c &= \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+c}{2}+\frac{b+c}{2} \\
a+b &\ge \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{a+c}{2} \\
a &\ge \frac{a+b}{2}\\
\end{align}

Thus,

$$(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{a+c}{2}, \frac{b+c}{2})  \prec  \left(a,b,c\right)
$$

Hence by Karamata's Majorization Inequality,

\begin{align}
f(a)+f(b)+f(c)&\ge f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(\frac{a+c}{2})+f(\frac{b+c}{2})\\
\iff \;\;\; a \ln a + b\ln b + c \ln c &\ge (\dfrac{a+b}{2}) \ln \frac{a+b}{2} + (\dfrac{a+c}{2})\ln \frac{a+c}{2} + (\dfrac{b+c}{2}) \ln \frac{b+c}{2}\\
\iff \;\;\; a^ab^bc^c &\ge \ (\frac{a+b}{2})^{\frac{a+b}{2}} (\frac{a+c}{2})^{\frac{a+c}{2}} (\frac{b+c}{2})^{\frac{b+c}{2} }
\end{align}

**Hint for the second question**

Let $k=a+b+c\,$. $\;f(x)=(k-x) \ln x\;$ is strictly concave for all $x \in [0,k]$. Use Karamata's Majorization Inequality as above or simply use Jensen Inequality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However could you please provide any other method (AM GM or power theorem) to solve it ( since I require it in an exam and we haven't learnt about Karmata/Jensen yet)?